# asp.net mvc razor slip checkbox can not hit to check

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I have problem with my View in asp.net mvc project. I added new checkboxFor element on this view:

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="checkbox clip-check check-primary">
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsHomePage)
          <label for="isHomePage">
             Is Home Page
          </label>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is my css:

```
.clip-check {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-left: 0;
 }

.clip-check label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 23px;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

    .clip-check label:before {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #c8c7cc;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        left: 0;
        margin-right: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 0;
        top: 1px;
        transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
    }

    .clip-check label:after {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 11px;
        height: 19px;
        left: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1px;
        transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
        width: 19px;
    }

.clip-check input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

    .clip-check input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
        border-width: 10px;
    }

    .clip-check input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
        color: #fff;
        content: "\f00c";
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
    }

    .clip-check input[type="checkbox"][disabled] + label {
        opacity: 0.65;
    }

        .clip-check input[type="checkbox"][disabled] + label:before {
            background-color: #F8F8F8;
        }
```

but after built and check from browser, I am not able to hit to check this checkbox, even I have done successfully with other checkbox as well. I am using bootstrap. Much appreciate to any help, thank you. 
[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "but after built and check from browser, I am not able to hit to check this checkbox". Do you mean that click on the label does not toggle the checkbox?

Comment: Which checkbox you've trouble to toggle its state (checked/unchecked)? Any other ways the checkbox can be "checked" rather than clicking inside the box?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider: yes, I meant clicking on checkbox from browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just checked carefully your css, you wrote everything for label element. You already hided checkbox input and draw the rectangle by css as well. Please see this code:

```
.clip-check label {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 13px;
margin-right: 15px;
padding-left: 30px !important;
position: relative;
line-height: 23px;
transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.clip-check label:before {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #c8c7cc;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 0;
    top: 1px;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.clip-check label:after {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 19px;
    left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
    width: 19px;
}
```

So if your label is not pointed to exactly the checkbox input with Id is `IsHomePage` (what will be rendered from asp.net server) then the style will not be changed `:after`. So your problem here :

```
<label for="isHomePage">
```

Please change `isHomePage` to `IsHomePage`, because of name of your field is IsHomePage.